# Controlling Form Field Dimensions

Tags: html, css

For the form below, how could I make the field 500 pixels wide and 30 pixels high?

```
echo '<form action="http://www...com/.../search2.php" method="post"> 


    <div class="searchtext"><label for="title">Search</label></div> 
    <div class="searchfield"><input type="text" name="find"></div>


    <div class="searchbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go"></div> 
</form>
';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please learn basic css http://www.tizag.com/cssT/

`<input type="text" name="find" style="height:30px; width:500px">`